# getting a new differential equation from an old one.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the following logistic differential equation:

> $$f'(x) = f(x)(1-f(x)), f(0) = 1/2 $$ and suppose that $ x = 2y - a$ for some positve constant $a$.

How do I write a differential equation involving $y$? i.e. a differential equation with the independent variable as $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y = \frac 12 (x+a)$.

Then change $f'(x) \rightarrow f'(2y-a)(2y-a)' =2f'(2y-a)(y'(x))= {f'(2y-a)} \\ f(x) \rightarrow f(2y-a)$

The new one is $f'(2y-a)=f(2y-a)(1-f(2y-a)) , \ f(0)=\frac 12$

Or suppose $g(y) = f(2y-a)$ to get $g'(y)=2g(y)(1-g(y)), \ g(\frac a2)=\frac 12$

(Note: $\frac {df}{dx} = \frac {dg}{dx} = \frac {dg}{dy}\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {g'(y)}{2}$)